# Can't detect if property does not exists in the location object

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to check if there is a type property in the location object and the type should be gold, the output for this condition is working but when the property is not present the else log does not get printed.. 
I already tried hasOwnProperty and this.props.location.type in replace for the 'in' method below, both didn't work..

```
 if('type' in this.props.location && this.props.location.type == 'Gold')
   {
       console.log('Gold member')
   } else {
       console.log('not Gold member')
   }
```

Comment: did you try if location is always part of this.props?

Comment: yes...but i fixed this already after i move it from the constructor to willMount

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.hasOwnProperty` method to check if the property exists on the `location` props.

```
if(this.props.location.hasOwnProperty('type') && 
     this.props.location.type === 'Gold') {
  console.log('Gold member');
} else {
  console.log('not Gold member');
}
```